# Trouble integrating BouncyCastle Jar

Tags: java, jar, bouncycastle

Okay, I'll say now that I know very little about Java. I was given the Bouncy Castle Jar and told that would contain what I needed to do this assignment. The Jar file is `bcprov-jdk15on-147.jar`. I'm also doing this on a Unix machine maintained by my school, so I can't go in and play with all of the Java files.

When I compile my class using Javac (specifically I use the command `javac -classpath bcprov-jdk15on-147.jar encrypt.java`), it compiles without error, but when I go to run the program afterward using the command `java encrypt`, I get this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/BouncyCastleProvider
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:276)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
```

My Jar file is located in my main folder with all of my other files, just in case it has to go somewhere special and that's what I didn't do.

When I do `java -classpath bcprov-jdk15on-147.jar encrypt` this is the error I get:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: encrypt
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: encrypt
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:276)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
```

Why am I having trouble running the compiled program?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Type this for running the program:

```
java -classpath bcprov-jdk15on-147.jar:. encrypt
```

That's because your program also needs to have any libraries it uses as part of the classpath at the time of running, not only at compile time.

Comment: Aha!. It was a classpath problem. And what is this "slightly different error" you're getting now? I updated my answer to also take into account the local classpath, try it again.

Comment: Once I'm allowed to in 4 minutes, I will!

Comment: is there some setting you can set so that you dont need to do this at run time? my classpath has this jar already.

Comment: @n00b if it's there already, then there isn't anything else to do. Otherwise, your classpath might not be correctly set.