# Portecle software converting from pem to bks - install error NoClassFoundException

Tags: java, android, ssl, noclassdeffounderror, pem

I want to use **.pem** format certificate and **.pkey** key in order to create a socket SSL in android. Unfortunately, I found at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390967/how-to-use-key-and-pem-file-to-create-a-socket-ssl-in-android) that android prefers a different format, the BKS format.  As described at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390967/how-to-use-key-and-pem-file-to-create-a-socket-ssl-in-android), we can convert PEM to BKS via the [Portecle](http://portecle.sourceforge.net/).

However i cannot install Portege in Ubuntu. When  i run:

```
java -jar /usr/share/java/portecle.jar
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/openssl/PasswordFinder
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)

    ...

    ...
```

**UPDATE**

I forgot to  transfer the **bcprov.jar**  to the

> /usr/share/java

folder.

I transferred it. But now, when i  running

```
 java -jar /usr/share/java/portecle.jar
```

,i get:

```
no main manifest attribute, in /usr/share/java/portecle.jar
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble integrating BouncyCastle Jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134161/java-having-trouble-integrating-bouncycastle-jar)

Answer (score 2):

I just followed these steps:

- Downloaded .zip from: [http--sourceforge.net/projects/portecle/](http://sourceforge.net/projects/portecle/)
- Exploded the .zip file
- Noticed in README.txt that the minimum requirement is Java SE 6
- Executed `java -version` and noticed the default one in my system PATH to be `java version "1.7.0_65"`
- Executed `java -jar portecle-1.7/portecle.jar`, and it just showed up the application without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Initially have to download bouncycastle:

http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-ext-jdk15on/1.46/bcprov-ext-jdk15on-1.46.jar

Use this commend in command prompt :

```
keytool -importcert -v -trustcacerts -file "oldfilelocation\mycertfile.pem" -alias ca -keystore "newfilelocation\keystore.bks" -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath "jarfilelocation\bcprov-ext-jdk15on-1.46.jar" -storetype BKS -storepass password
```